# Visualizer Rhythmbox-plugin-visualizer

Tags: rhythmbox, visualization

I'm new to Rhythmbox, but I got the visualizer plugin, yet it still won't display anything when I open it. What am I doing wrong? Why won't it display anything?

Comment: Could you please provide version numbers for your Ubuntu install, Rythmbox, and the plugin?